# Makefile variable issue, make wants to create "*.o" instead of foo.o bar.o etc

Tags: c++, makefile

I thought this would be simple but I can not get it to work. When I run the command

```
make --dry-run
```

On this makefile:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -std=c++11
SRCS = *.cpp
OBJS = (SRCS:.cpp=.o)

testprogram: $(OBJS)
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS)

%.o: %.cpp
 $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS)  $< -o $@
```

I would expect it to be processing the compilation line in the form:

```
g++ -c -std=c++11 foo.cpp -o foo.o
```

However, it is showing this command:

```
g++ -c std=c++11 foo.cpp -o *.o
```

So, it is trying to create a file "*.o" instead of the desired object file target. What has gone wrong here?

Comment: See [Makefile wildcard](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html).

Comment: Yup, the docs cover exactly this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok thanks to the comment of @Juanchopanza, I have seen my mistake.

The third line needs to become:

```
SRCS = $(wildcard *.cpp)
```

A simple SRCS = *.cpp is not correct

Comment: You are also allowed to select your own answer. Since it is correct, it makes sense to do so.